# Setting Up a Remote Employee Clocking System with Biometric Recognition

Tags: laravel, client-server, system, communication

I need to set up a remote clocking system for my employees as they have the flexibility to come in whenever they want. This system should be capable of remotely storing employees' arrival and departure times using iris and fingerprint recognition.

My questions are as follows:

1. What hardware do you recommend for this system?
2. How can I register users with their biometric information?
3. I want to have two or three remote devices acting as clients, along with an administrator interface to control all devices. How can I set up this architecture?

I would really appreciate any help you can provide. As a Laravel developer, I have skills in web development, but I am new to the field of biometrics and setting up remote clocking systems.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,
Ben Becker

In a high school of commerce, I found two electronic devices equipped with fingerprint readers and cameras for facial recognition. I believe that the cameras can be considered as users. And from these devices, authentication can be performed.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for a forum or discussion board rather than Stack Overflow, as it's more of a general and opinion based and doesn't directly involve coding or programming issues.